# Import error ghmm library

Tags: python, linux, import, importerror, hidden-markov-models

i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ghmm.py", line 112, in <module>
    import ghmmwrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ghmmwrapper.py", line 25, in <module>
    _ghmmwrapper = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ghmmwrapper.py", line 21, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_ghmmwrapper', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libghmm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo locate libghmm
/usr/local/lib/libghmm.a
/usr/local/lib/libghmm.la
/usr/local/lib/libghmm.so
/usr/local/lib/libghmm.so.1
/usr/local/lib/libghmm.so.1.0.0
```

Why go i get this error? i tried adding

```
/usr/local/lib/
```

to my PYTHONPATH

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PYTHONPATH` is working for python modules, not for system libraries.

You can add the local path to your system:

1. Edit as root `/etc/ld.so.conf`
2. Add a new line with `/usr/local/lib`
3. Save and quit
4. Run "sudo ldconfig"

Then restart your application, it will work.

If you don't want to change anything to your system, you can use the environment variable:

```
LD_PRELOAD_PATH=/usr/local/lib python <yourapp.py>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cd ~  
vi .bashrc  
#at the end of file add:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
# relogin terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to just execute ***sudo ldconfig*** for run-time bindings.