# ImportError with pythons libghmm library

Tags: python, linux, import, importerror, hidden-markov-models

I have followed the [installation directions](http://ghmm.org/) to install the GHMM library.  However, I still get the following error:

```
Python 2.6.6 (Apr 11 2011, 15:50:32) 
[GCC 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ghmm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ghmm.py", line 112, in <module>
    import ghmmwrapper
  File "ghmmwrapper.py", line 25, in <module>
    _ghmmwrapper = swig_import_helper()
  File "ghmmwrapper.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    import _ghmmwrapper
ImportError: libghmm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to change my `LD_PRELOAD_PATH` variable to `/usr/local/lib` to no avail.

Also, when I try to locate libghmm, I get the following, so the libraries are definitely there:

```
% locate libghmm
/usr/local/lib/libghmm.a
/usr/local/lib/libghmm.la
/usr/local/lib/libghmm.so
/usr/local/lib/libghmm.so.1
/usr/local/lib/libghmm.so.1.0.0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Or `LD_PRELOAD` (no _PATH)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216059/import-error-ghmm-library, unless you would like to tell us how your problem is different . . .

Comment: Actually, I am responding to that question.  I did what the answer suggested, which is to set `LD_PRELOAD_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib`, but that did not work.  That's why I posted the question again to see if there are other ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: what happens when you `import _ghmmwrapper` in an interpreter?

Comment: No need to reply, I figured this out.  I forgot to run `ldconfig`.  :-)